# Python ASYNCIO ContentTypeError: 0, message='Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype

Tags: python, api, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

```
ContentTypeError: 0, message='Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype: application/octet-stream', url=URL('https://api-reports-prod-usamazon.s3.amazonaws.com/atvpdr-a2vzay-report-data-7aaf8bfa-5cb5-4c76-b430-01d68cd7024b.json.gz?X
```

When i try to get the `gzip` file located in a `S3 Bucket` through Python - asyncio method i'm getting above Error.

**Synchronous Code [Working]**

```
report = requests.get(location, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(gzip.decompress(report.content))
```

**Asynchronous Code [Not Working]**

```
async def get_data(session, url):
    async with session.get(url,headers=headers) as resp:
        data = await resp.json()
        return data 
  
async def main(req_url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        url = req_url
        tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_data(session, url)))
        data = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

start_time1 = time.time()
nest_asyncio.apply()
keyword_list = asyncio.run(main(location))
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time1))
```

Thanks in Advance.

Tried

```
async def get_data(session, url):
    async with session.get(url,headers=headers) as resp:
        data = json.loads(gzip.decompress(resp.content))
        return data
```

Which is throwing an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-397-2f3527a7a82e>", line 20, in <module>
    keyword_list = asyncio.run(main(location))

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 32, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(future)

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 70, in run_until_complete
    return f.result()

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 178, in result
    raise self._exception

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 280, in __step
    result = coro.send(None)

  File "<ipython-input-397-2f3527a7a82e>", line 15, in main
    data = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 349, in __wakeup
    future.result()

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 280, in __step
    result = coro.send(None)

  File "<ipython-input-397-2f3527a7a82e>", line 3, in get_data
    data = json.loads(gzip.decompress(resp.content))

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\gzip.py", line 547, in decompress
    with GzipFile(fileobj=io.BytesIO(data)) as f:

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'StreamReader'
```

'''

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: why do you use `resp.json()` if you send `gzip` file ? You should get `resp.content` or even `json.loads(gzip.decompress(report.content))` like in `Synchronous Code`

Comment: this should give you gzip file - if you want to get JSON then `return json.loads(gzip.decompress(await resp.content))` but I'm not sure if `resp.content` needs `await`

Answer (score 1):

If you use synchronous code

```
report = requests.get(location, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(gzip.decompress(report.content))
```

then you should do similar in asynchronous code

After digging I found that it needs [await resp.read()](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.BaseRequest.read) instead of `resp.content`

```
async with session.get(url,headers=headers) as resp:
    data = json.loads(gzip.decompress(await resp.read()))
    return data
```

---

You forgot `return data` in `main()`

---

I don't have access to gzip file with JSON data so I tested it on JSON from https://httpbin.org/get

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import time

# --- functions ---

async def get_data(session, url):
    async with session.get(url, headers=headers) as resp:
        #return await resp.json()
        #return json.loads(gzip.decompress(await resp.read()))
        return await resp.read()

async def main(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = asyncio.ensure_future(get_data(session, url))
        data = await asyncio.gather(tasks)
    return data
    
# --- main ---

headers = {}

location = 'https://httpbin.org/get'

start_time = time.time()

keyword_list = asyncio.run(main(location))
print(keyword_list)

end_time = time.time()

diff_time = end_time - start_time

print("---", diff_time, "seconds ---")
```

Comment: I tried json.loads(gzip.decompress(resp.content)) but i get a output string named StreamReader.

Comment: Using the above code i get the following error
ContentTypeError: 0, message='Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype: application/octet-stream', url=URL('https://crmi-api-reports-prod-usamazon.s3.amazonaws.com/atdsdker-a2vjt-report-data-5354ads6c-60dd-40b7-a1ca-fa0a0sde6.json.gz?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=2021das2930Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=30&X-Amz-Credential=AHF6GH/20210724/us-north-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=38b5619b326042c1a42141240d0fcd9c6842443e8')

Comment: after digging in code and I found that it uses `await resp.read()` instead of `resp.content`. See new code in answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot furas it worked, also it will be helpful for me improve my knowledge if you could share any documentation/article on the issue if you have.

Comment: I don't have documentation/article - I use Google when I have problem. If I can't find documentation then I open source code to see how it works.